# I am using this code to change a button title but it is not working. It just refreshes with the xib title

Tags: ios

```
 (IBAction)detailSongsButton:(id)sender {

    switch (songsOrText) {
        case 0:
            _detailProductText.text = _songList;
            _detailSongsButtonLabel.titleLabel.text = @"Album Info.";
//            NSLog(@"_detaiSongsButtonLabel.titleLabel.text: %@",_detailSongsButtonLabel.titleLabel.text);
            songsOrText = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            _detailProductText.text = _productText;
            _detailSongsButtonLabel.titleLabel.text = @"Song List";
            songsOrText = 0;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are setting the button for the correct state, when it is selected it may be highlighted and change back to normal.

Try setting the title for all states as such:
[button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted| UIControlStateDisabled|UIControlStateSelected]